# Как удалить полноэкранный режим у главного окна?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, gui

Не подскажете, как убрать возможность изменения размера окна с использованием *PyQt5*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore


class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setWindowFlags(window.windowFlags() & ~QtCore.Qt.WindowMaximizeButtonHint) # Так мы убираем возможность нажать кнопку развернуть окно
    window.setFixedSize(window.size()) # а так устанавливаем фиксированный размер окна, без возможности изменить размер мышкой 
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Все заработало!)

Comment: @Bitchdragon Если  ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour